# Debugging an iOS app on an M1 Mac from Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, apple-m1, visual-studio-mac

With the new M1 Mac:s, it is possible to run iOS apps, even apps distributed via AppCenter.

But, is it possible to deploy and debug a Xamarin iOS app directly to an M1 Mac from *Visual Studio for Mac*?

Apparently, *XCode* supports debugging iOS apps directly on the M1 Mac, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/running-your-ios-apps-on-macos).

[image: Xcode lists my Mac as deployment option]

In *Visual Studio for Mac*, looking in the list of devices for *iPhone* deployment, I can see my USB connected iPhone/iPad devices, but the M1 Mac is not listed. Nor is it listed among the *iPhone Simulator* devices.

[image]

Is there any way to get the Mac listed among the devices so that I can deploy my iOS app directly to the Mac?

Comment: Currently debugging iOS apps directly on the M1 Mac with Visual studio is not supported , you can raise you question on DC for better support: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=41.

Comment: Thanks, [I did that as well yesterday](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debugging-an-ios-app-on-an-m1-mac-from-visual-stud/1559268), still waiting for feedback.